# Вопрос по background-image в css?

Tags: css, css3

Подскажите как решить эту задачу?

Есть Bootstrap 4 - Row, ему в стилях в отдельном классе указан **background-image** файл в формате **svg**.
Row автоматически растягивается по ширине на всю страницу с фиксированным размером по высоте.

Вопрос:
Как сделать так чтоб background-image всегда заполнял 100% размеры Row - по **высоте** и **ширине**. То есть - нужно чтоб background-image растягивался на весь Row **без сохранения пропорций** так как высота у нас фиксированная а ширина зависит от разрешения экрана.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение своей проблемы: именно в случае с SVG файлами для того чтоб все нормально растягивалось на весь экран **без сохранения пропорций**, нужно обязательно чтоб в файле svg было указано preserveAspectRatio="none" , тогда все будет нормально растягиваться как и с png и jpg файлами.

Вот что было:

```
<svg width="1440px" height="381px" viewBox="0 0 1440 381" version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

Стало:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1440 381" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

Может кому пригодится. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Свойство background-size?

```
{
    background-image:    url(images/background.svg);
    background-size:     100% 100%;                     
}
```

Для сохранения пропорций используется специальные значения contain или cover.

Соус: https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_stretch_background_image.cfm

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, и за ссылку - в этом примере все работает, и действительно помогло мне понять что не так. **Но** в примере используются gif или png файлы - в случае с ними все ок , а у меня svg - и это почему то не работает именно с svg =(